# Difference between

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I am creating a simple login page by email and password. I have a class LoginViewModel that will have a User class as a member variable inside it. The class contains the emailAddress. The password is inside the main LoginViewModel. My User class reference is like this:

```
public User User { get; set; }
```

when the user fills the email address and password and hit submit, the LoginViewModel correctly binds the field to the email address inside the User class from the view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User.Email) // m is the LoginViewModel model
```

I want to know why it doesn't work if I had the code above looked like this instead:

```
public User User = new User();
```

It shows the email inside the User instance as null value. I know that the use of the constructor is probably better than both, but what is the difference between these two.

EDIT#1:
On posting at the "Login" action method, this finds the value I entered for the email field in the model:

```
public User User { get; set; }
```

this one does NOT:

```
public User User = new User(); // --> because of this email field value shows up null
```

Comment: @GrantWinney I think the OP means using a public field in the expression mapping, instead of a property.

Comment: Your edit does indeed show that my answer was not what you were after. I've deleted it: I do not see how to edit it into a form that does answer your question, and when the question is shown not having good answers, others are more likely to make an attempt of their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of the `DefaultModelBinder` which will only bind properties with public getter/setters. If you explore the source code, the process includes initializing a new instance of your model and then attempting to set the value of its properties. The key part here is

```
protected virtual void SetProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, object value)
{
  ...
  if (!propertyDescriptor.IsReadOnly && !isNullValueOnNonNullableType)
  {
    ...
    propertyDescriptor.SetValue(bindingContext.Model, value) // this is where the value is set
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

When you use `public User User = new User();` you only creating a field and the `IsReadOnly` property of its `PropertyDescriptor` will return `false` so the code in the `if` block is never executed and the value of `User.Email` is `null` (the default value for `string`)

Comment: That's what I was exactly looking for... happy to participate in you breaking the 10K mark!

Answer (score -2):

```
I want to know why it doesn't work if I had the code above looked like this instead:

public User User = new User();
```

Because the infrastructure looks for the `set` method. It needs to be property with public setter.

The peace of code provided by @Stephen doesn't describe the heart of problem.
Here is the `DefaultModelBinder`'s method which tries to bind properties of model.

```
private void BindProperties(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
     IEnumerable<PropertyDescriptor> properties = GetFilteredModelProperties(controllerContext, bindingContext);
     foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in properties)
     {
          BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, property);
     }
}
```

Here we see that `GetFilteredModelProperties` tries to get `PropertyDescriptor` which by chain of methos calls ends up by method call `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties` which returns the properties of type not the fields.

Comment: Wow..., and where is comments?

Comment: I disagree with the rating; this answer actually may be useful. Could you elaborate on your answer @hamlet? Whose infrastructure? C# or MVC?

Comment: I'd disagree on that. If a field is supposed to be public, it does not really need `set`. I know it's a good practice to use `{ get; set; }` methods and make a property, though.

Comment: @ZikO, Your gut feeling is not in account! Have you tried?

Comment: @user1019042, The ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @ZikO, The question is tagged MVC and model-binding. Of course it needs a setter - the `DefaultModelBinder` initializes the object and then sets its properties on post back. If there is no setter then binding fails. This answer is correct (although perhaps not well explained)

Comment: Hample, no I did not try it. 

Stephen. Thanks for pointing this out. I wasn't aware of `DefaultModelBinder`. If @user1019042 used a field `public User User;` without `{ set; get; }` meaning there was no setter again, would it work? In the end, in a block of code, there is no difference whether values is assigned to a field or a property. The notation is the same, such as  `Something.User = ...`. It seems not to make any difference whether there is empty setter or just a public field. Based on what I have learned, it's surprising that `DefaultModelBinder` requires even empty setter.